# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<'(T_SL) on line 2 using php heredoc syntax

Tags: php

When I run this code on my editor, it returns an error.

My php version is **5.4.35**

Code:

```
<?php
$name = <<<SQL my name is amit
SQL;
echo $name;
?>
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<'(T_SL) on line 2

Can someone please explain why this error, or what my script is missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What is _<<<SQL my name is amit
SQL;_ ? What are you trying to do there?. Is that meant to be a string?

If so, you need to have `$name = "<<<SQL my name is amit SQL";`

Comment: heredoc syntax: `<<<` After this operator, an identifier is provided, __then a newline__

Comment: @James - Nope, there are several ways of defining strings, and only two of them require quotation marks

Comment: @Markbarker could you please drop an example?

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't even realize that existed as a concept! You learn something new every day.

Comment: @James - you also have an alternative called nowdoc.... both heredoc and nowdoc are explained in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker neat! A side of PHP I never knew about, and I considered myself extremely proficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heredoc syntax requires a newline character immediately after the identifier, before the string content:

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.

```
$name = <<<SQL
my name is amit
SQL;
echo $name;
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/vqQn1a)

Comment: I was preparing an answer; may as well scrap eeeeverything that I "typed" lol

Comment: Sorry Fred.... been offline for a couple of days, so eager to get back into the fray